# Use Extract Text Webpack Plugin in Laravel Mix

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I try to use Css-Modules in Laravel-Mix.

I install it (`laravel-mix-react-css-modules`) via `npm` configure in `mix` .But have a little problem that css module's styles loaded as `<style>` tag inside `<head>` tag.

To solve this problem and load style's properly I need to install and configure `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to my **mix.config**.

Firstly I install alpha version of extract-plugin **4.0.0-alpha.0**

After I try to configure it in my **webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
let webpack = require('webpack');
require('laravel-mix-react-css-modules');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .reactCSSModules('[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')
    .sass('resources/sass/main.scss', 'public/css')
    .version();

mix.webpackConfig({
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            'react',
            'lodash',
            'jquery',
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            names: ["commons", "vendor"],
            filename: 'js/[name].js',
            minChunks: 2
        }),
    ],
    module: {
    rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(pdf|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]?[hash]'
            },
            // --- CONFIG FOR EXTRACT-TEXT-WEBPACK-PLUGIN ----
            {
            test:  /\.s[ac]ss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
               fallback: 'style-loader',
               use : [
                  {
                    loader : 'css-loader',
                  },
                  {
                    loader : 'sass-loader',
                  }
               ]
           })
        }
    ]
}
```

});

But this won't work.

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, according to the author of the plugin, laravel-mix-react-css-modules is not fully compatible with Laravel Mix 4 yet: https://github.com/leinelissen/laravel-mix-react-css-modules/issues/3